# Mongodb collection limit using limit()

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Im getting about 600 documents and i wish to limit to 50. Wherever i put .limit(50) it breaks. Is there some other solution for collection:

```
app.post('/numbers', function (req, res){
    console.log(req.body);
    db.senzori.insert(req.body, function (err, doc) {
        res.json(doc);
    });
});
```

Comment: Show us the query when you get all 600 docs and when limit not work. All should be good if you just use something like this. db.collection.find({query}).limit(50).toArray(callback)

Comment: sry, i copied insert insted of find, app.get('/numbers', function (req,res) { 
 db.numbers.aggregate({$limit:20}, function (err, docs){  
  res.json(docs);
 });
});

Comment: and i get it working this way, inserting aggregate instead of find